# Facebook graphapi page/feed returning items sorted by relevance instead of recent activity

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi I am using the Facebook graph api tool and attempting to get the feed of a public page. I want to get most recent comments first. However the feed returns comments and replies sorted by "relevance", is there a "sort" I can apply or how do I change this to get recent comments and replies within my posts?
I do not own the page I am getting the feed from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the `order` parameter for comments, which can have the following values:

> - chronological
> - reverse_chronological

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.5#ordering

As far as I know, the feed's posts will always be sorted by `created_time`, and there's no way to influence this via the Graph API requests.

Comment: Thanks for the response Tobi, it seems to depend on the setting of the public page. So if no ordering is applied the feed returns the default setting for the page, most likely ordered by "Relevance". If I apply the sort order for reverse_chronological I get most recent comments first. However I need to replicate how facebook return "Recent activity"; they have comments sorted to the top of the page, if they have a reply within them that is recent.

Comment: That's not possible IMHO, as I wrote. Look at the according docs.

Comment: Yeah it seems not unfortunately.